# Python: h2o detailed documentation

Tags: python, documentation, h2o

I feel really dumb right now, but, what I am dealing with for the last 15 minutes is that I want to find detailed [h2o](https://www.h2o.ai/) documentation.

My problem is that I have `h2o.save_model()` method and I want to know, which parameters to use and how. So, I wrote "python h2o.save_model()" to [Google](https://www.google.com/) and I was expecting something similar to [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) in case of writing "python pandas.DataFrame.groupby". However, the only link I found is [this one](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-xu/6/docs-website/h2o-docs/save-and-load-model.html), which does not provide a detailed description of a method.

What am I doing wrong? Does detailed h2o documentation exist? If so, could you provide me a link, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that's what you're looking for: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/h2o.html#h2o.save_model

Please also note that you can access clients documentation from http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/api-reference.html (agree that it's a bit hidden...).

Like for any other Python function, you could also use `help(h2o.save_model)` from the Python repl, or `h2o.save_model??` from IPython/Jupyter.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is exactly what I was looking for <3

Comment: I really do not follow why the h2o doc is so messy, there are quite a few versions deployed in a few places, and in many cases it is hard to find what I need. This even makes TensorFlow doc look better in comparison, hmm.

Comment: @VincentYuan it's hard for me to completely disagree with you on this topic: the doc structure is quite old, but we can try to improve its usability.
What is your main issue? H2O doc for Py in particular? Can't find the H2O function for a common functionality (even with the search field)? Can't find details or examples about a given function? Cross-referencing?

Comment: Hi @Seb, are you working at h2o? I can share a few pain points for the Python H2O doc: first of all, put all source of truth in one place, including the doc and the code examples. Then need to optimize the doc structure, for instance, make the doc for each class concise instead of putting them all in one long page, because that leads to searching results linked to multiple classes. also, can optimize the table of content to link to deep level of sections, say methods.  I believe some modern framework like mkdocs-materials provide a good solution, just fyi.